# How to set max_allowed_packet in h2 database for testing

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, blob, h2

I am using Spring Boot application. In **h2** database, I am using **BLOB** type to store the large data. Currently **BLOB** size is **4GB** in h2, I want to set the limit for BLOB type and do testing with multiple inputs (**lesser** size).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 4 GB is the max size of a file of FAT/32. I doubt that there is any configuration for H2

Answer (score 0):

H2 actually can handle LOBs larger than 4 GiB, there is no such limit in H2 and there is no global configuration for it.

You can only specify maximum length in definition of particular column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tableName(
…,
columnName BLOB(1000000),
…);
```

https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#binary_large_object_type

If you use JPA with auto-generated schema, take a look on `columnDefinition` or `length` attributes of `@Column` annotation.

Comment: I had already set length. It doesn't work. I set like this   @Column(name = "file", nullable = false, length=41943040)

Comment: I want to set like lower limit like 5MB.

Comment: 41943040 is significantly larger than 5MB, you need to decrease this value. Also you need to check how database schema was created, if you have separate scripts for it, you need to check data type of this column in them.